# Pass a list through a function and create a summary df

Tags: r, list, function, for-loop

I want to pass a list to a function which pulls journey information from Tfl's API (legs, walk time, duration etc) and outputs a summary df of this info.

This is an example of what my list `taxi.args.new` looks like (list length is 1):

[image]

I can run the code below for **a list with length 1 only** by referencing the 1st element (it works fine):

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
library(tidyverse)

# this function works for the list taxis.args.new (calling the first element)

api_function <-function(from, to, date, time, timeIs, journeyPreference, accessibilityPreference, walkingSpeed, cyclePreference, bikeProficiency){
  
  tflpath <- "https://api.tfl.gov.uk/Journey/JourneyResults/{from}/to/{to}?date=[date]&time=[time]&timeIs=[timeIs]&journeyPreference=[journeyPreference]&mode=tube%2Cbus%2Coverground&accessibilityPreference=[accessibilityPreference]&walkingSpeed=[walkingSpeed]&cyclePreference=[cyclePreference]&bikeProficiency=[bikeProficiency]"
  
  dat <- data.frame()
  
  for (i in 1){
    request      <- GET(url = tflpath, query = taxi.args.new[[i]])
    json_content <- fromJSON(content(request, "text"), flatten = TRUE) 

    # obtain info about journey legs
    df           <- as.data.frame(json_content$journeys$legs)

    # obtain info about journey origin and destination
    od           <- as.data.frame(json_content$journeyVector)[,2:3]

    df1          <- df[,c("duration", "mode.id")]

    # tidy the df to get summary of legs, duration, walk time etc
    df2          <- df1%>%
                     group_by(mode.id)%>%
                     summarise(legs = n(), total_dur = sum(duration))%>%
                     mutate(tube_legs = case_when(mode.id== 'tube'~ as.numeric(legs) ,
                                 mode.id== 'walking'~ 0,
                                 mode.id== 'bus'~ 0),
                           bus_legs  = case_when( mode.id== 'tube'~ 0,
                                 mode.id== 'walking'~ 0,
                                 mode.id== 'bus'~ as.numeric(legs)),
                           walk_legs = case_when(mode.id== 'tube'~ 0,
                                 mode.id== 'walking'~ as.numeric(legs),
                                 mode.id== 'bus'~ 0),
                           walk_dur  = case_when(mode.id== 'walking' ~ as.numeric(total_dur), TRUE ~ 0))%>%
                    ungroup()%>%
                    select(-mode.id)%>%
                    summarise(total_legs  = sum(legs),
                              total_dur   = sum(total_dur),
                              tube_legs   = sum(tube_legs),
                              bus_legs    = sum(bus_legs),
                              walk_legs   = sum(walk_legs),
                              walk_dur    = sum(walk_dur))%>%
                    cbind(od)%>%
                    cbind(min(df$departureTime), max(df$arrivalTime))%>%
                    rename(dep_time = "min(df$departureTime)" ,  arrival_time = "max(df$arrivalTime)")%>%
                    select(from, to, dep_time, arrival_time, tube_legs,
                    bus_legs, walk_legs, total_legs, walk_dur, total_dur)
                  
          dat <- append(dat, df2) 
          }
return(dat)
}

## this returns a df which summarises jny info 
test_df <- as.data.frame(do.call(api_function, taxi.args.new[[1]]))
```

This is what `test_df` looks like:

[image]

However, I want to scale up and do this for a list of length 200k and cannot figure out how to do this. I want the output to be a df with all results appended together. So it'd look a bit like this (example with just 2 rows):

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. You can probably tell I had already tried to so something (hence the for loop in the code)

**UPDATE:**

Thanks so much to Ronak for his suggestion. Here is the final result tidied up:

```
api_function <- function(from, to, date, time, timeIs, journeyPreference, accessibilityPreference, walkingSpeed, cyclePreference, bikeProficiency){
  
  tflpath <- "https://api.tfl.gov.uk/Journey/JourneyResults/{from}/to/{to}?date=[date]&time=[time]&timeIs=[timeIs]&journeyPreference=[journeyPreference]&mode=tube%2Cbus%2Coverground&accessibilityPreference=[accessibilityPreference]&walkingSpeed=[walkingSpeed]&cyclePreference=[cyclePreference]&bikeProficiency=[bikeProficiency]"
  
  request      <- GET(url = tflpath, 
                      query = list( from                     =from,
                                    to                       =to,
                                    date                     =date,
                                    time                     =time,
                                    timeIs                   =timeIs,
                                    journeyPreference        =journeyPreference,
                                    accessibilityPreference  =accessibilityPreference,
                                    walkingSpeed             =walkingSpeed ,
                                    cyclePreference          =cyclePreference,
                                    bikeProficiency          =bikeProficiency))
  json_content <- fromJSON(content(request, "text"), flatten = TRUE) 
  # obtain info about journey legs
  x            <- flatten(json_content$journeys$legs)
  # obtain info about mode and duration of each leg
  df1          <- data.frame(duration = x$duration, mode.id  = x$mode.id)
  # obtain info about journey origin and destination
  od           <- as.data.frame(json_content$journeyVector)[,2:3]
  
  df2 <- df1%>%
    group_by(mode.id)%>%
    summarise(legs = n(), total_dur = sum(duration))%>%
    mutate(tube_legs       = case_when(mode.id== 'tube'~ as.numeric(legs) ,
                                       mode.id== 'walking'~ 0,
                                       mode.id== 'bus'~ 0,
                                       mode.id== 'overground'~ 0),
           bus_legs        = case_when(mode.id== 'tube'~ 0,
                                       mode.id== 'walking'~ 0,
                                       mode.id== 'overground'~ 0,
                                       mode.id== 'bus'~ as.numeric(legs)),
           walk_legs       = case_when(mode.id== 'tube'~ 0,
                                       mode.id== 'walking'~ as.numeric(legs),
                                       mode.id== 'bus'~ 0,
                                       mode.id== 'overground'~ 0),
           overground_legs = case_when(mode.id== 'tube'~ 0,
                                       mode.id== 'walking'~ 0,
                                       mode.id== 'bus'~ 0,
                                       mode.id== 'overground'~ as.numeric(legs)),
           walk_dur        = case_when(mode.id== 'walking' ~ as.numeric(total_dur), TRUE ~ 0))%>%
    ungroup()%>%
    select(-mode.id)%>%
    summarise(total_legs      = sum(legs),
              total_dur       = sum(total_dur),
              tube_legs       = sum(tube_legs),
              bus_legs        = sum(bus_legs),
              overground_legs = sum(overground_legs),
              walk_legs       = sum(walk_legs),
              walk_dur        = sum(walk_dur))%>%
    cbind(od)%>%
    cbind(min(x$departureTime), max(x$arrivalTime))%>%
    rename(dep_time = "min(x$departureTime)" ,  arrival_time = "max(x$arrivalTime)")%>%
    select(from, to, dep_time, arrival_time, tube_legs,
           bus_legs, walk_legs, overground_legs, total_legs, walk_dur, total_dur)
  return(df2)
}

results <- do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_along(taxi.args.new), function(x) do.call(api_function, taxi.args.new[[x]])))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `lapply` :

```
result <- do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_along(taxi.args.new), function(x) 
                  do.call(api_function, c(taxi.args.new[[x]], x))))
```

Or with `purrr` :

```
library(purrr)
result <- map_df(seq_along(taxi.args.new), 
                 ~invoke(api_function, c(taxi.args.new[[x]], .x)))
```

I have changed function a bit and added another argument `i` to it.

```
api_function <-function(from, to, date, time, timeIs, journeyPreference, accessibilityPreference, walkingSpeed, cyclePreference, bikeProficiency, i){
  tflpath <- "https://api.tfl.gov.uk/Journey/JourneyResults/{from}/to/{to}?date=[date]&time=[time]&timeIs=[timeIs]&journeyPreference=[journeyPreference]&mode=tube%2Cbus%2Coverground&accessibilityPreference=[accessibilityPreference]&walkingSpeed=[walkingSpeed]&cyclePreference=[cyclePreference]&bikeProficiency=[bikeProficiency]"
    request      <- GET(url = tflpath, query = taxi.args.new[[i]])
    json_content <- fromJSON(content(request, "text"), flatten = TRUE) 
    # obtain info about journey legs
    df           <- as.data.frame(json_content$journeys$legs)
    # obtain info about journey origin and destination
    od           <- as.data.frame(json_content$journeyVector)[,2:3]
    df1          <- df[,c("duration", "mode.id")]
    # tidy the df to get summary of legs, duration, walk time etc
    df2          <- df1%>%
      group_by(mode.id)%>%
      summarise(legs = n(), total_dur = sum(duration))%>%
      mutate(tube_legs = case_when(mode.id== 'tube'~ as.numeric(legs) ,
                                   mode.id== 'walking'~ 0,
                                   mode.id== 'bus'~ 0),
             bus_legs  = case_when( mode.id== 'tube'~ 0,
                                    mode.id== 'walking'~ 0,
                                    mode.id== 'bus'~ as.numeric(legs)),
             walk_legs = case_when(mode.id== 'tube'~ 0,
                                   mode.id== 'walking'~ as.numeric(legs),
                                   mode.id== 'bus'~ 0),
             walk_dur  = case_when(mode.id== 'walking' ~ as.numeric(total_dur), TRUE ~ 0))%>%
      ungroup()%>%
      select(-mode.id)%>%
      summarise(total_legs  = sum(legs),
                total_dur   = sum(total_dur),
                tube_legs   = sum(tube_legs),
                bus_legs    = sum(bus_legs),
                walk_legs   = sum(walk_legs),
                walk_dur    = sum(walk_dur))%>%
      cbind(od)%>%
      cbind(min(df$departureTime), max(df$arrivalTime))%>%
      rename(dep_time = "min(df$departureTime)" ,  arrival_time = "max(df$arrivalTime)")%>%
      select(from, to, dep_time, arrival_time, tube_legs,
             bus_legs, walk_legs, total_legs, walk_dur, total_dur)
    return(df2)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but neither of those work; I get 'anonymous function' window pop up and it doesn't give me any clear indication of what the problem is. Just to be clear, I changed the for loop to read ```for (i in 1:2)``` to test it on a list of length 2 that I have

Comment: The loop is applied by `lapply` or `map`. Revert the code back to `for(i in 1)` or better remove the `for` loop completely because it isn't really needed here. `api_function` should work for only 1 instance and loop should be applied from outside.

Comment: Now I am horribly lost. You're probably going to have to spell this out to me like I am five.

Comment: What happens if you keep your function as it is that you have in your post and use my answer for data with 2 rows?

Comment: So, if I keep the for loop in as you suggested and use ```result <- map_df(taxi.args.new, ~invoke(api_function, .x))``` it returns a 2 row df, but both of the rows are identical. And yes, ```length(taxi.args.new)``` is 2. Hopefully this makes sense to you!

Comment: Ohh..that is because `i` is always 1 in `taxi.args.new[[i]]`. I have done some modifications in your function and my answer to make this work. Although this is not the best possible way to write a function but this should work. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks so much Ronak - I used the lapply suggestion and it worked :-). Curious to know what isn't good about the function? (I will gladly take criticism!)

Comment: I'll not comment on the body of the function since I don't have the data to see what would be the optimal way to write it. But in the function there are all the column names as function argument but there is also `taxi.args.new[[i]]` which has all the data that you need. So I think it is better to use one of the method. Either pass all the column names separately as you have now and instead of using `taxi.args.new[[i]]` use the arguments that you have passed to build `taxi.args.new[[i]]` or just pass `i` to the function and get all the data from `taxi.args.new[[i]]`. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: That makes perfect sense - I have amended the code to reflect this.